# Why is it wrong to say this sentence 'I'm afraid I forgot my homework at home

Tags: differences

Why is it wrong to say this sentence and what grammar rules are broken

Comment: Why do you think it's wrong? Who told you that it is wrong? The meaning of the sentence is very clear. It might not be the most formal way to phrase this sentence, but I don't think it's *wrong* (or at least not in an obvious way).

Comment: Because you're going to be in big trouble.  Again.

Comment: I am being told "I forgot my wallet at home." is wrong. However, I find it to be supremely idiomatic. I would say it's short for "I forgot [to grab and begin carrying] my wallet [while I was] at home." It's the only way I ever hear native speakers declare they are unable to pay or show ID. This means it's not wrong.

Answer (score 11):

If someone told you that

> I'm afraid I forgot my homework at home.

is wrong, the only possible reason is that that someone believes you should have said either:

> I'm afraid **I forgot my homework**. I left it at home.

or

> I'm afraid **I left my homework at home**.

The string "I forgot my homework at home" is ambiguous. When you were at home and supposed to be doing your homework, did you forget that you had homework to do? If so, then you should say:

> I'm afraid that after I arrived home yesterday, I forgot that I had homework to do, so I didn't do it.

The problem is one of semantics, not grammar. Say what you mean and mean what you say.

However, most native speakers would understand your sentence to mean that you were claiming two things:

> (1) I did my homework.

and

> (2) I forgot to bring it with me. It's still at home.

Answer (score 0):

The verb *forget* does not take an indirect object marked by *at*, whereas *leave* may.

So, in

> I left my homework at home.

the *at home* phrase is an argument of the verb, specifying its meaning.
whereas in

> I forgot my homework at home.

it is not, and can only be an adjunct: specifying where the action took place, not being part of the meaning of the action. Furthermore, *forget* in the special sense of *leave behind* (as opposed to *forget about*) is not really compatible with such a locational phrase.

As Frustratedwithformsdesigner says, the second sentence is understandable in context, but it is not something that a native speaker would say, except in the rather unusual meaning where *at home* is an adjunct; something like

> I was thinking about my homework all the time I was at the gym, and then on the bus, but I forgot my homework at home.

For your meaning, either

> I forgot my homework.
>   or
>   I left my homework at home.
>   would be the normal ways to express it.

Comment: This is precisely when _forget_ means “to leave behind unintentionally,” and I don't see how it's incompatible with a location. Indeed, Wiktionary uses it in the example of _leave behind_ meaning “to forget”: _We (accidentally) **left behind** our bags at the airport._ (I personally would rephrase that as _We left our bags behind at the airport,_ but I guess they wanted to stress the phrasal verb.)

Comment: "...it is not something that a native speaker would say..." is always a dangerous thing to say. Native speakers will say anything, even "educated" native speakers. Maybe "...it's not something that a **careful** native speaker would say unless inebriated..." is more or less true. :-)

Comment: @Bradd: perhaps it is compatible with a location for you, but not for me, and the result strikes me as unnatural. And we are talking about _forget_, not _leave behind_: words with the same semantics may have quite syntactic constraints.

Comment: @BillFranke: yes, perhaps it's an overgeneralisation. But I am _emphatically_ not talking only about careful native speakers: it is my claim (though I am open to counter argument) that it is not something natural to any native English speaker.

Comment: I am a native speaker, and I find it entirely natural. _Forgot at home_ means _left at home._

Comment: OK. Our idiolects are different.

Comment: I too find it perfectly natural—and moreover, it is semantically different from “I left my homework at home”. _Left_ implies (or at least makes it possible) that the homework was intentionally left at home, while _forgot_ clearly says that it was unintentional.

Answer (score -1):

When I look at this, the way I see it as being wrong is that you left out the word "that": "I'm afraid *that* I forgot my homework at home."

Without the "that," you technically have two complete sentences: "I'm afraid." "I forgot my homework at home." This is technically a run-on.

Although, in informal English, I'd say this is fine.

Comment: *That* is optional in this sentence; there's nothing wrong with it as written.